# How to understand "upon signing accept something"?

Tags: meaning

I'm reading a document and there is a sentence which is:

> Reviews and Authorisations
>
> The people listed have reviewed this document and [upon signing accept] the obligations and conditions set out below

I don't understand the part inside brackets.

I understand *upon doing something*, but the word *accept* is a verb, not a noun. How am I to understand it?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this wording smacks of [legal writing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_writing). I'd expect to see this phrasing in a formal document, but I would avoid this wording in everyday conversation.

Comment: It becomes clear if you make a pause: The people... and upon signing, (they) accept...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Upon signing* is a prepositional phrase meaning "with the act of signing". *Accept* is not the object of the verb *sign* but the main verb in the sentence's second clause, modified by the prepositional phrase. The sentence might be clearer if it were pointed differently:

> The people listed have reviewed this document and, upon signing, accept the obligations and conditions set out below.

It may be paraphrased:

> The people listed have reviewed this document. By signing, they accept the obligations and conditions set out below.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, very clear, that I can understand it now.